# Roolback no Mysql 5.7 Workbench não funciona! Ajuda

Tags: mysql

Ola galera tudo bem ? Sou novo no Mysql, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.

estou usando um comando que não é DML.

porém quando dou roolback, ocorre o erro abaixo. Será que é alguma configuração

de permissão no workbench , tipo esse auto commit ali?

(uso wampserver)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente está utilizando tabelas no formato **MyISAM** que não tem suporte a transações.

Ao invés disso utilize tabela no formato **InnoDB**.

Como criar tabelas nesse formato:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT, b CHAR (20), PRIMARY KEY (a)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Também é possível alterar essa informação na opção de operação da tabela:

[image: Alterar para InnoDB]

Comment: vixi, deu certo!!! terei que estudar sobre MyIsan e InnoDB para entender as diferenças
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como nosso amigo ali em cima disse, o roolback não funciona em MYisan . tem que criar a tabela para innodb